# iPhone: Application submission in AppStore

Tags: iphone

I want to submit my application in AppStore. After i have gone through the docs there, i see i should go to iTunes Connect and fill the form to submit my application in AppStore. If someone already did it, can you guys please share your suggestion? 
I did build 'Distribution' in my Xcode project and compressed my app ready, i want to upload it in AppStore as i have already a developer account. 
** I also want to know, should my build be created using 'Distribution' configuration and built with Distribution provisional file? I have three provisional file created such as Main provisioning profile in 'Provisioning->Development' tab in Portal and Ad-hoc, AppStore provisional profiles in 'Distribution' tab in Portal. Which one i should use in Xcode and build my application to upload that in AppStore? Can i use any one of the three?
**Can i go to iTunes Connect and fill the form to upload my app? During filling the form it asks for 'Does your product contain encryption?' Why is that and what does it mean? After further filling up the details, will it ask me to upload my Zipped application(myApp.app file) there? How would be the process further, just give me some brief idea please?

Clave/

Comment: I Don't know if this Question is still alive, but in your research journey have you found anything regarding encrypted compressed files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also want to know, should my build
>   be created using 'Distribution'
>   configuration and built with
>   Distribution provisional file?

Yes. Your build must be signed with distribution profile. And do not forget about Entitlements.plist file

> Can i go to iTunes Connect and fill the form to upload my app?

Yes :)

> After further filling up the details, will it ask me to upload my Zipped application(myApp.app file) there?

Yes, there will be a screen where you should upload your zipped binary (as well as 512x512 Application icon and screenshots)

> How would be the process further, just give me some brief idea please?

You'll need to fill some forms - application description, category, pricing, stores where distribute your app, some questions to rate your app (in case it contain "objectionable" contents) etc
Anyway (IMO) everything is user friendly and clear there.

Comment: As you said, "And do not forget about Entitlements.plist file" in your comment, i got a doubt that Entitlements.plist file should be created only when we create Ad Hoc Distribution right as Apple said "For App Store Distribution, skip to Step 12. For Ad Hoc Distribution, complete the following:" there. Then why should i create Entitlements.plist file for uploading my app in AppStore ? Please clarify it?
Which one(profile) should i add in Xcode to build my app to upload in AppStore?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It seems I have been wrong about Entitlements.plist file

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload your app to the app store you must build with a distribution profile, thats pretty much all you need...If you dont know what using encryption means then odds are you are not using encryption so check no for that...after that its pretty straight forward you fill out the info form and submit it for review. If at any step you do something (such as use a wrong provisioning profile) itunes connect will tell you and wont let you proceed, so if you succesfully finish submitting the app then you are good to go...there is also an itunes connect guide you can use here https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Comment: I also have a doubt that, why do we need to create three provisioning profiles? I created three provisional profile such as Main provisioning profile in 'Provisioning->Development' tab in Portal and Ad-hoc, AppStore provisional profiles in 'Distribution' tab in Portal. Why can't we use only one profile for all work? Which one(profile) should i add in Xcode to build my app to upload in AppStore? I read that doc but not able to understand very clearly to know why do we need to have one provisional file in Development tab and two in Distribution section?

Comment: "If you dont know what using encryption means then odds are you are not using encryption so check no for that..." Not true, just using HTTPS for anything more than authentication counts as encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

On the right of the page, there is a section called "App Store Resource Center", and inside of that there are some great resources like [Preparing your App for Submission](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/appstore/submission.html), etc.

Also, under the [Distribution](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action) section of the Program Portal, there are some answers to questions like how to build and zip your app for submission, and properly configuring Xcode for the build.

Encryption:

The reason it's asking you for this information is because there are laws around exporting certain types of encryption.  You would know if you are using this in your application.  If you said yes, there would be some follow up questions and it might lock your application to the US App Store only if your encryption was too high to export.  For more information on encryption, your friendly neighborhood search engine can do the rest :)

Comment: Created a 'Distribution' configuration by choosing Duplicate configuration in Xcode project info Configurations tab. Is this the right way of creating Distribution configuration?

Comment: How can i verify that my build has built properly for uploading it in AppStore?As Apple doc said in 'Verifying a Successful Distribution Build' section,Build Log detail view should show about signing confirmation.But when i built my application, i didn't see any such log message in my project detail log.Is that must to show the confirmation on detail log after building the project?(or)What other way to confirm it? I got that when we upload our applicaiton through iTunes connect, it will not accept our app if it is wrongly built, but still i want to make sure that while building our app itself.

Comment: The way they suggest is to make a copy of the Release build flavor, and use that.  The point is to make sure it's an optimized build, but you have probably done this correctly from the way it sounds

Comment: Xcode 3.1 and 3.2 have different build logs.  If you are using 3.1 you can see the log by clicking a tiny icon in the lower left that looks like lines, in 3.2 this "detail" icon will be displayed next to each build message group, but it changes depending on the view

Comment: also, you can always do an xcodebuild from the command line and just watch it that way

Comment: You are right. But as Apple says, i'm not seen '"embedded.mobileprovision" and “CodeSign” in the Build Log detail view.

Comment: open up your xcodeproj as a folder from Finder with "view contents" from the right click menu and then open those files up with your favorite text editor and post them here

Comment: Thanks veru much. Finally i successfully resoved it. Problem was sue to my Xcode, which seemse to be corrupted. I re-installed it and resolved the problem of creating AppStre distribution build.